# Search by artist using libspotify on windows?

Tags: windows, spotify, libspotify

The api is very poorly documented and I am very confused. The method sp_search takes parameters (sp_search* search, int index). How do I create an sp_search object?

Answer (score 0):

Full documentation for libspotify can be found [here](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.45/index.html). Search functions are under "Modules" then "Search".

The `spshell` example that comes with libspotify contains a full implementation of search in the `search.c` file. It's done like this:

```
sp_search *newSearch = sp_search_create(session,
    "foo fighters", //query
    0, // track_offset
    100, //track_count
    0, //album_offset
    100, //album_count
    0, //artist_offset
    100, //artist_count
    0, // playlist_offset,
    100, // playlist_count
    SP_SEARCH_STANDARD, // search type
    &search_complete, //callback
    NULL); // userdata

void search_complete(sp_search *result, void *userdata) {

    int trackCount = sp_search_num_tracks(search);

    for (int currentTrack = 0; currentTrack < trackCount; currentTrack++) {
        sp_track *track = sp_search_track(search, currentTrack);
        // Do something with track...
    }
}
```